# parse error - invalid geometry even though ST_ISVALID returns true

Tags: postgis

I have a function to return a reduced size version of the geometries in our database.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fog.small_kml(
    shape geometry,
    max_length integer)
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
 DECLARE kml text;
 DECLARE tolerance float;
BEGIN
    tolerance:=0.001;
    SELECT ST_ASKML(shape) INTO kml;

    WHILE LENGTH(kml) > max_length LOOP
        SELECT ST_ASKML(ST_SIMPLIFY(shape, tolerance)) INTO kml;
        tolerance = tolerance + 0.001;
    END LOOP;

    return kml;
END
 $BODY$;
```

when I run this on certain geometries I get get the result

```
ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "<M" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry
SQL state: XX000
```

occurring due to the statement `SELECT ST_ASKML(ST_SIMPLIFY(shape, tolerance)) INTO kml;`. However, `ST_ISVALID` says that the geometries are all valid.

Is there anything I can do to force the geometries into a state where I can simplify them? The length of the KML is around 12 million characters for the largest, which is why I want to simplify (and why I can't paste the whole thing here).

Each one starts `<MultiGeometry><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>` and I've had no issues with them before other than being slow. It seems to be `ST_SIMPLIFY` only that has an issue.

Comment: The simplify operation can make a geometry invalid if it collapses holes. Have you tried to test the validity *after* `ST_Simplify`?

Comment: @Vince, I can't test validity after ST_Simplify as ST_Simplify errors.

Comment: Actually, no, I was wrong, it's the ST_ASKML failing on the simplified geometry. I'll look into this.

Comment: Yes, Vice was correct and changing the line to `SELECT ST_ASKML(ST_SIMPLIFY(ST_MAKEVALID(shape), tolerance)) INTO kml;` fixes it. I'll leave a while to let him answer. If he doesn't I'll self answer.

Comment: Go ahead and self-answer (though the MakeValid *before* Simplify confuses the issue of where invalidity arose).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vince got it correct in the comments - simplification led to an invalid geometry and then it was the `ST_AsKML` function which threw the error.

I fixed it by changing that line to

```sql
SELECT ST_AsKML(ST_MakeValid(ST_Simplify(shape, tolerance))) INTO kml;
```